# Не работает переход из одного состояние в следующее

Tags: python, aiogram

Не работает переход из состояния name в состояние client_phone_number, бот просто зависает. Код разбит на файлы, поэтому прикрепил только нужные для вопроса.

handlers\client.py

```
from aiogram import types
from config import *
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from data_base import sqlite_db
from bot_dp_create import *
from keyboards.client_kb import menu_kb, orders_kb, faq_kb, info_kb, faq_answer_kb, info_answer_kb, orders_fsm_kb


class FSMClient(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    client_phone_number = State()
    model = State()
    service = State()


# Основные функции


async def start(message: types.Message):  # Функция для команды start, с использование клвиатуры с меню
    await message.answer(start_message)
    await message.answer(text="Меню", reply_markup=menu_kb)


async def home(callback: types.callback_query, state=FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if not (current_state is None):
        await state.finish()
    await bot.edit_message_text(message_id=callback.message["message_id"], chat_id=callback.message['chat']['id'],
                                text="Меню", reply_markup=menu_kb)
    await callback.answer()


async def orders_f(callback: types.callback_query):
    await bot.edit_message_text(message_id=callback.message["message_id"], chat_id=callback.message['chat']['id'],
                                text="Услуги", reply_markup=orders_kb)
    await callback.answer()


async def orders_name(callback: types.callback_query):
    await FSMClient.name.set()
    print("photo set")
    await bot.edit_message_text(message_id=callback.message["message_id"], chat_id=callback.message['chat']['id'],
                                text="Введите имя", reply_markup=orders_fsm_kb)



async def orders_client_phone_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    print("second started")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    # await bot.delete_message(message_id=message["message_id"], chat_id=message['chat']['id'])
    await FSMClient.next()
    await message.answer("Введите контактный номер телефона", reply_markup=orders_fsm_kb)



async def faq_f(callback: types.callback_query):
    await bot.edit_message_text(message_id=callback.message["message_id"], chat_id=callback.message['chat']['id'],
                                text="Часто задаваемые вопросы", reply_markup=faq_kb)
    await callback.answer()


async def faq_answer(callback: types.callback_query):
    answer = faq[callback.data[4:]]
    await bot.edit_message_text(message_id=callback.message["message_id"], chat_id=callback.message['chat']['id'], text=answer, reply_markup=faq_answer_kb)
    await callback.answer()


async def info_f(callback: types.callback_query):
    await bot.edit_message_text(message_id=callback.message["message_id"], chat_id=callback.message['chat']['id'],
                                text="Информация", reply_markup=info_kb)
    await callback.answer()


async def info_answer(callback: types.callback_query):
    answer = info[callback.data[5:]]
    await bot.edit_message_text(message_id=callback.message["message_id"], chat_id=callback.message['chat']['id'], text=answer, reply_markup=info_answer_kb)
    await callback.answer()


def register_handlers_client(dp: Dispatcher):  # Функция для регистрации хендлеров в основном файле

    dp.register_message_handler(start, commands=['start'])
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(home, text='home', state="*")
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(orders_f, text='orders')
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(orders_client_phone_number, state=FSMClient.name)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(faq_f, text='faq')
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(faq_answer, Text(startswith='faq_'))
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(info_f, text='info')
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(info_answer, Text(startswith='info_'))
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(orders_name, text="create_order", state=None)
```

keyboards/client_kb

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from config import faq, info

home_b = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Домой", callback_data='home')

menu_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
menu_orders_b = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Услуги", callback_data='orders')
menu_info_b = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Информация о магазине", callback_data='info')
menu_faq_b = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Часто задаваемые вопросы", callback_data='faq')

menu_kb.add(menu_info_b, menu_orders_b, menu_faq_b)


orders_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

orders_create_b = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Записаться на сервис', callback_data='create_order')
orders_check_b = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Проверить заказы', callback_data='check_orders')

orders_kb.add(orders_create_b, orders_check_b, home_b)


orders_fsm_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

orders_fsm_kb.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отмена", callback_data="home"))

faq_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

for element in faq.keys():
    faq_kb.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=element, callback_data="faq_" + str(element)))

faq_kb.add(home_b)


faq_answer_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
back_to_faq_b = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад к часто задаваемым вопросам", callback_data="faq")

faq_answer_kb.add(back_to_faq_b, home_b)


info_answer_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
back_to_info_b = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад к информации", callback_data="info")

info_answer_kb.add(back_to_info_b, home_b)



info_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

for element in info.keys():
    info_kb.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=element, callback_data=f"info_" + str(element)))

info_kb.add(home_b)
```